# How to simultaneously scroll two windows?

Tags: variables, scroll, scrollbar, autohotkey, code-duplication

I want to [simultaneously scroll two windows](https://superuser.com/a/326826/301042), but the hotkey input method requires me to duplicate it multiple times. My idea is to use [Function Hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Function) and [`A_ThisHotKey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey) variable, but the `WheelDown` is disable in the program if using this script:

```
WheelDown::
ScrollKey := A_ThisHotKey
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Writer
{
        CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
        WinGet, active_id, ID, A
        IfWinExist, Sumatra
        {
                Send {ScrollKey}
                WinActivate ; Automatically uses the window found above.
                Send {ScrollKey}
                Send {ScrollKey}
                WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
        }
}
Else
{
        Send {A_ThisHotKey}
}
return
```

I want `ScrollKey` to match `WheelUp`, `WheelDown`, `PgUp`, `PgDn`, `Up`, `Down`.

**Ideally**, I think the script should detect how much the first program is scrolled, then apply that amount to the second one. Advantages:

- Scrolling will be seamless since the other program are scrolled in the background
- Clicking on the scrollbar works
- Different scrolling speeds don't affect the comparison
- Moving lines in text editors won't scroll pages in PDF viewers

[image]

<sup>FYI: [Send/SendRaw/SendInput/SendPlay/SendEvent: Send keys & clicks](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Click)

[How to grab the scrolling amount in one window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48437716/3416774)

Also asked on Reddit: [How to simultaneously scroll two windows?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/7snibx/how_to_simultaneously_scroll_two_windows/?st=jct6i35e&sh=ced546b8)</sup>

Comment: I tried to use `A_ThisHotKey` but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi Ooker, if any of the answers solved your problem, feel free to mark it as the answer so this question is no longer "_unanswered_" in the search results :)  -  If no answer is sufficient, yet, feel free to comment and/or add information to your question regarding your specific problem.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMangelsdorf, thank you so much for your effort. Unfortunately I haven't tried your method yet for having done with the project. As I haven't confirmed whether it works or not yet, I think accepting it I think it would be misleading for future viewers. If that's not a problem I'm willing to do it, as there is a higher chance that it just works :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#SingleInstance Force
Process, Priority, , High

; SetTitleMatchMode, 2

GroupAdd, Scroll_Group, ahk_class Notepad
GroupAdd, Scroll_Group, ahk_class Notepad++

SetWinDelay 0

#If (WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") && WinExist("ahk_class Notepad++")) || (WinActive("ahk_class Notepad++") && WinExist("ahk_class Notepad"))

    WheelUp::
    WheelDown::
    PgUp::
    PgDn::
    Up::
    Down::  
        MouseGetPos, mX, mY
        Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}
        GroupActivate Scroll_Group  ; activate the next window of this group
        If (A_ThisHotKey = "WheelUp" || A_ThisHotKey = "WheelDown")
            MouseMove, 200, 200, 0  ; move the mouse over the currently active window 
        Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}   
        GroupActivate Scroll_Group
        MouseMove, mX, mY, 0
    return

#If
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Using the classes or the processes of the programs when adding them into the group doesn't work. And why do you use specific value of coordinates of the mouse (`MouseMove, 200, 200, 0`)?

Comment: Try my edited answer with Notepad and Notepad++. On my system WheelUp/WheelDown only work if the mouse pointer is over the window that has to be scrolled, therefore the MouseGetPos and MouseMove commands in the code.

Comment: it adds `0xd0450` in the second window if up or down arrow keys are hold, and `d0450` if PgUp and PgDn are hold. Do you know how to detect the scrolling amount? See my edit in the question

Answer (score 2):

Based on [user3419297's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369932/2822719), this modified script allows you to define the titles of the two apps you want to scroll at the top of the script once:

```typescript
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#SingleInstance Force
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Process, Priority, , High
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

; Set your desired app names here. It is enough to use a part of the window's title
PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A := "Notepad++"
PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B := "Word"

GroupAdd, Scroll_Group, %PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A%
GroupAdd, Scroll_Group, %PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B%

SetWinDelay 0

#If (WinActive(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A) && WinExist(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B))
    || (WinActive(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B) && WinExist(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A))

    WheelUp::
    WheelDown::
    PgUp::
    PgDn::
    Up::
    Down::  
        MouseGetPos, mX, mY
        Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}
        GroupActivate Scroll_Group  ; activate the next window of this group
        If (A_ThisHotKey = "WheelUp" || A_ThisHotKey = "WheelDown")
            MouseMove, 200, 200, 0  ; move the mouse over the currently active window 
        Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}   
        GroupActivate Scroll_Group
        MouseMove, mX, mY, 0
    return
```