# How to grab the scrolling amount in one window?

Tags: scroll, scrollview, autohotkey

This is the first step to [scroll two windows simulteneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48365826/3416774), the second step is to find a way to apply that amount to the other program. But I really don't know where to start, all I see in from Google is about modifying the behavior of **the scroll of the mouse**, not the **scrolling amount in one window**. Advantages of using this instead of listening to the keys:

- Scrolling will be seamless since the other program are scrolled in the background
- Clicking on the scrollbar works
- Different scrolling speeds don't affect the comparison
- Moving lines in text editors won't scroll pages in PDF viewers

[image]

Comment: seems like a complex problem. For a simple solution, I would try to send the same scroll event to the second window (just need to find out how to send events to specific app without losing current focus). But if you want to 'sync' the scroll position, I think it would be really hard. Reading the scroll position and scroll range itself seam too hard - I tried to do it once but gave up quickly.

Comment: @MikhailV how did you do that back then?

Comment: I've read related topics on AHK's forum, e.g. this: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/97328-scrollbar-position/  there some links to other related topics, but frankly that was too much for me. So I wanted to read and then write the scroll position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you what I would do, but it's not going to be fun...

Assuming the text is roughly evenly distributed (which it might not be between two languages like that, and two windows with different text sizes and widths, really consider this carefully before you do the work), then the goal is to force both scroll bars to be at the same percent relative to their whole. So what you need to do is write a function to determine what percent each scroll bar is at. I would screen capture both windows and crop out the important parts of the scroll bar like this:

[image]

Specifically the up and down buttons, the top of the scroll handle, the bottom of the scroll handle. Save them in their own files. Do it for both windows in case they draw their scroll bars a little differently.

Now the tricky part. Write a function that does the following: imagesearch for the top button within rightmost 25 pixels or of the specified window. Same for the bottom button. Same for the top of the handle. Same for the bottom of the handle.  Use this to determine where your window is.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; so it matches the end of the title
WinGetPos , X, Y, Width, Height, LibreOffice Writer ;exact substring of window name required
```

Use something like this to find the scroll bar parts.

```
CoordMode, Pixel , Screen ;so image search searches entire screen
barwidth = 25 ; make sure it's more than the bar is wide.
ImageSearch, TopButtonX, TopButtonY, X+Width-barwidth , Y, X+Width, Y+Height, TopButton.bmp ; no jpg, fuzzy edges make searches fail
```

Then do some math, something like:

```
TopButtonY := TopButtonY+TopButtonImageHeight ; because we only care about the position of the bottom of the button.
BottomHandleY := BottomHandleY+BottomHandleImageHeight   ; because we only care about where the bottom of the handle is.
HandleHeight := TopHandleY - BottomHandleY ; how tall the scroll handle is
TotalHeight := TopButtonY - BottomButtonY - HandleHeight ;how tall the scroll field is
HandleOffset := TopHandleY - TopButtonY ;how far it is from the top
HandlePercent := HandleOffset / TotalHeight ; the part we care about. return this value
```

With a function like that, you can know how scrolled each window is. All that's left is to send the scroll commands. There's a few choices.

```
; ControlSend , Control, Keys, LibreOffice Writer
ControlSend , Control, {Pgdown}, LibreOffice Writer ; or {Pgup}
ControlSend , Control, {WheelUp}, LibreOffice Writer ; or {wheeldown}
ControlSend , Control, {Up}, LibreOffice Writer ; or {down}
```

If it lets you move the caret with up/down arrows while the window is inactive, that is probably the most precise option, even if it takes a bit longer. The fastest most precise way is to simulate a click drag also using control send. To use ControlSend you need to figure out which control you're working on. WindowSpy can help you with that.

So first: Find the scroll positions of both windows. Second determine which window is active. Third, nudge the inactive window in the correct direction. Repeat until they're within a certain tolerance range (otherwise it will bounce up and down endlessly).

I can't emphasize this enough, but please make sure that getting the scroll bars in approximately the same positions is sufficiently close before even attempting this. If it isn't, you will have wasted a lot of time fiddling with it. Keep in mind it will be less and less accurate the longer the text is.

If it is an option, I would definitely consider copying the contents of both windows into a program that gives you more access to the controls (or better one that is specialized for this purpose). If you had more access, you could use the paragraph breaks to line up the texts with far more precision.

If you really just want to see both texts side by side (and the paragraphs do line up), you could find a text editor that tells you information like this:

[image]

If autohotkey will let you read the text of that information, you can copy the PDF into autohotkey's memory (separated by line) and use autohotkey to show only the corresponding paragraph of the PDF as you move around in the editable document.

Hope something I said helps, good luck.

Comment: Do you think the handles in the image are approximately in the same position? All I can make sure is the amount of the scrolling will be the same. It seems that grabbing this is not easy, and it's up to the programs to provide the API on this, is it?

Comment: They look like they're in approximately the same position, but you're very near the top, and that's 309 pages projected onto 520 pixels. That's around 2 pixels per page, it leaves very little room for error. If the number of pages ever exceeds the number of pixels, you are guaranteed to have a problem, even if the texts were identical and the scrollbar detector is written perfectly. It is not the ideal approach.

Comment: If the paragraphs are guaranteed to line up between the two languages, that simplifies things: I'm assuming you're just using the PDF program as a text viewer, and that the editor (libreoffice) can change too. So all you need is to find an editor that makes the line number (literally how many '\n' come before the caret) available to autohotkey (or whichever language ends up being most convenient). Then you can copy the contents of the PDF to the clipboard, split it by '\n', and use your own program to focus on the paragraph that matches the paragraph the editor has currently.